# Very difficult to diagnose Asp.net WebForm process sequence resulting in duplication of actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, webforms

**General Description**
I find myself having to diagnose a very annoying yet serious issue with such simple code that it is inexplicable where the problem could be coming from.

Our website allows a user to click a Contact Me button, fill in some details and the end result is that someone at one of our branches should recieve an email telling them to contact person X, and the event is logged to the database in an audit table.

**Symptoms**
At times the notification and audit log actions are being completed multiple times. **NOTE: This is steps 5 and 6 in the diagram and both are duplicated when this happens, it's never one or the other.**

1. The number of duplications is not consistent. Sometimes you get 2 emails and 2 audit logs, sometimes 3 sometimes more.
2. The occurrence of the problem is not consistent

**Diagram**
The diagram illustrates the sequence of events.

[image]

**Attempted Solutions**
Here's what I've tried so far:

- User Error (Clicking multiple times) - I assumed that the user might be clicking the Submit button more than once [the server can be a bit slow to respond sometimes and based on the fact that it's an iframe dailog they wouldn't see that it is actually being processed], which would account for the fact that this is happening intermittently and a variable number of duplications occur. To this end we added code to hide the entire form on clicking submit and replaced it with a loading GIF to give the user feedback and prevent them from clicking submit again.
- User Error (F5 and Ok) - I also thought the user might be hitting F5 and resubmitting the form. However, after submission our forms redirect to another page altogether so refreshing will only result in a Thank You page being reloaded. Can't be that.

### The Code

**WebForm Button_Click handler**
Sequence (4) in the diagram.

```
protected void ContactSendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            Communications.SendContactUsEmail(FromName.Text, FromEmail.Text, FromPhone.Text, BranchID);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**Send Email Notification**
Sequence (5) in the diagram.

```
public void SendContactUsEmail(string name, string email, string phone, int branchID)
{
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("webmaster@oursite.com", "agent@oursite.com");
    mailMessage.Subject = "Contact Request";
    mailMessage.Body = "Name: " + name +
                        "\r\nEmail: " + email +
                        "\r\nPhone: " + phone;

    try
    {
        smtp.Send(mailMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        //log entry should only be created if the message was sent without error
        CommunicationsData.LogContactCompanyDetails(name, email, phone, branchID);
    }
}
```

**Audit Log Entry**
Sequence (6) in the diagram.

```
public void LogContactCompanyDetails(string name, string email, string phone, int branchID)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionString))
        {
            var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.CreateContactAuditLog", _sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("from_name", name));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("from_email", email));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("from_phone", phone));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("branch_id", branchID));

            _sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            _sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

There's nothing complicated here so I'm at a loss and desperate!

Comment: I'm not sure what might be happening but you have a comment in your `finally` statement that is wrong.  `finally` is **always** called, even if there is an exception.

Comment: Don't do `catch (Exception ex)  { throw ex; }`, You destroy the original stack trace, making it _harder_ to find the root of the problem.Don't use a catch block unless you intend to do something with the exception (like log it).  In that case you would re-throw the exception with `throw;` rather than `throw ex;`

Comment: If there is a known delay between form submission and the display of the "thank you" page, perhaps the user's might click the browser back button and resubmit the form believing that the delay meant something didn't work?
Never underestimate the imagination and restlessness of Internet users... ;-)

Comment: @RickS - thanks for that, in the process of redacting the code I moved one or two things around. I'll move that back.

Comment: @DStanley - thanks for the tip I'll certainly remove them although, there are no exceptions being thrown. Everything in the code succeeds without failure.

Comment: @Culme - We actually added code, mentioned in the Attempted Solutions section, that prevents the user from manually taking double actions.

Comment: @Jaques, I noticed that you said you are hiding the form when the submit button is clicked. I meant that the user could back up and have it re-displayed and thus submit it again. Depending on the actual application, this may or may not be a plausible cause - I guess you've ruled it out.

Comment: Tip: Check the IIS logs to see if there are multiple requests at the time when multiple emails/loggings occur. That will help you in determining if the cause is due to multiple postbacks or ...something else.